# Polynomial Root finding bisection

Tags: algorithm, math, bisection

If I am finding the roots of a polynomial using the bisection method, and in some cases depending on the polynomial the roots might be negative or they may be positive.

I understand I can determine if the roots are going to be negative or positive, based on the result of evaluating the polynomial... however I am unsure what I would use as x.

Can anyone give any insight here?

Comment: This sort of question sounds like it would be better suited for Math.SE, or even SciComp.SE.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the roots can be negative or positive has nothing to do with the bisection method. The existence of a root can be proved using the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) from calculus.

So all you have to do is find points `x1` and `x2` such that `y(x1)` is negative and `y(x2)` is positive. Then you know from the IVT that there is a root between `x1` and `x2`. You do that by doing a binary search on that interval. If `y(x3) = y((x1+x2)/2)` is negative, then you repeat the bisection search on the interval `[x3,x2]`. Otherwise if it's positive, then search on the interval `[x1,x3]`.

It doesn't matter whether the root is negative or positive. I'm not sure if that answers your question, but I hope that helps you understand the algorithm.

Comment: Of course, not all polynomials have (real) roots; e.g., 1 + x^2. There are also polynomials with real roots (e.g., x^2) that never change sign.

Answer (score 0):

Many root-finders allow the user to supply a starting point or points to begin searches. This allows users to try to "fiddle" the results to find different roots or allow the finder to converge to a root.

If it does not make sense to allow a user to provide starting values you could begin by probing a handful of points:

- -1, 0, 1
- -10, 0, 10
- -100, 0, 100
- etc.

If the input is an odd polynomial, this will eventually discover a suitable range for bisection. If the input is an even polynomial, you might never catch sign changes (consider f(x)=x^2 -- it is never negative), so be prepared to give up after a certain (configurable?) amount of probing.

I've suggested making the ranges larger by powers of 10 here; since the bisection approach cuts the range in half each time, perhaps this is too conservative. (It'll take between two and three iterations of the bisection to reduce a range to the next "tighter" bracket.) Maybe better would be larger jumps:

- -10, 0, 1
- -1000, 0, 1000
- -100000, 0, 100000
- etc.

This will perform fewer probes but require more bisection. Try a handful of polynomials and track execution time for finding the roots with both suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the bisection algorithm, you first need to find an interval which contains a root. The standard algorithm for this is given in [Sturm's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

However the standard bisection algorithm expects the signs of the function values in the endpoints to be different. This can be problem. The simplest example is x^2 which has the single root 0 of order 2. Since x^2 is positive for all non-zero x, you can not find an interval enclosing the root suitable for use with the bisection algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably find this helpful.

using System;

namespace Bisection_Method

{

```
class Program

{

    public double midPoint (double xl, double xu)

{

    return (xl + xu) / 2;

}

    public double function(double x)

    {

        return (x*x-2);

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        Program root = new Program();

        double xm=0, xl=1, xu=2, check=0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)

        {

            xm = (xl + xu) / 2;

            check = root.function(xl) * root.function(xm);

            if (check < 0)

                xu = xm;

            else if (check > 0)

                xl = xm;

            else if (check == 0)

            {

                break;

            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("The Approximate of the Root is {0}", xm);

    }

}
```

}

http://mustafa.amnbytes.com/2012/09/bisection-method-program-in-c.html

Comment: link only answers are generally discouraged.

Comment: Link only answers are fragile, as the link may break. Please elaborate on the link.

Comment: Here you go with the complete program!